# QT: Deleting item from Custom ListWidgetItem corrupting other entry in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qt6

I am working on the application (QT6) for which I need to implement custom ListWidgetItem,
I have implemented QCustomListWidgetItem class that is derived from QWidget.

**Code Summary:**
I am populating my dialog with these custom items labeled from 1 to 5, after that I am creating one async thread that will delete these items from dialog one by one.

**Problem:**
Only first item is getting deleted, afther that I can see stale item (2nd item got blank)
[image]

**Code:**

1. mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QListWidget>
#include <QLabel>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


//Custom WidgetItem
class UploadJobListDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UploadJobListDialog(std::vector<std::string> jobNames, QWidget* parent = NULL);
    void removeit(size_t i);


private:
    void addListWidgetItems();
    QListWidget* m_pListWidget = nullptr;

    std::vector<std::string> m_pJobNames = {};

};

class QCustomListWidgetItem : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit QCustomListWidgetItem(std::string labelText, QWidget* parent = NULL);

    private:

        QLabel* m_pItemLabel = nullptr;
        std::string m_pJobName;
};
```

2. main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>


QCustomListWidgetItem::QCustomListWidgetItem(std::string labelText, QWidget* parent)
: QWidget(parent), m_pJobName(labelText)
{
    m_pItemLabel = new QLabel(QString::fromStdString(m_pJobName), this);
}


UploadJobListDialog::UploadJobListDialog(std::vector<std::string> jobNames, QWidget* parent)
    : QDialog(parent) , m_pJobNames(jobNames)
{
    addListWidgetItems();
}

void UploadJobListDialog::addListWidgetItems()
{
    m_pListWidget = new QListWidget(this);
    QString listStyle(
        "QListWidget::item:hover,"
        "QListWidget::item:disabled:hover,"
        "QListWidget::item:hover:!active,"
        "{background:#FFFFFF;}");

    m_pListWidget->setStyleSheet(listStyle);
    m_pListWidget->setFixedSize(QSize(470, 150));

    for (const auto& jobName: m_pJobNames)
    {
        QListWidgetItem* listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem(m_pListWidget);
        QCustomListWidgetItem* customListWidget = new QCustomListWidgetItem(jobName, m_pListWidget);
        listWidgetItem->setSizeHint(customListWidget->size());
        listWidgetItem->setFlags(listWidgetItem->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
        m_pListWidget->addItem(listWidgetItem);
        m_pListWidget->setItemWidget(listWidgetItem, customListWidget);
    }
}

void UploadJobListDialog::removeit(size_t ui)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_pListWidget->count(); ++i)
    {
        sleep(10);
        QListWidgetItem* item = m_pListWidget->item(0);
        if (!item)
            continue;

        QCustomListWidgetItem* widget = dynamic_cast<QCustomListWidgetItem*>(m_pListWidget->itemWidget(item));
        if (!widget)
            continue;

        int nRow = m_pListWidget->row(item);
        QListWidgetItem* pDeleteItem = m_pListWidget->takeItem(nRow);
        if (pDeleteItem != NULL)
        {
            m_pListWidget->setItemWidget(pDeleteItem, nullptr);
            delete pDeleteItem;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   std::vector<std::string> jobs = {"1","2","3","4","5"};

   static UploadJobListDialog obj(jobs);

   std::thread([=]
           {
               obj.removeit(jobs.size());
           }
      ).detach();

   obj.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

1. Why item labeled 2 got stale?
2. Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is very much appreciated.

**PS: I am new to QT**

Comment: You're accessing/modifying the `UploadJobListDialog` from multiple threads simultaneously without any form of synchronization.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Only one thread is modifying, I dont think that should be the problem

Comment: As well as your own explicitly created thread the main/GUI thread is also accessing the object via the event loop (i.e. the `obj.exec()` call).

Comment: but when I am just susing QListWidgetItem (instead of custom) everything is working fine

Comment: It's [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).  That means anything can happen -- including it 'appearing' to work as expected.

Comment: How we can achieve synchronization in this scenario, I tried locking removeit function, but same behavior.

Comment: As it stands this looks like an XY problem.  Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do and why you think you need a separate thread to do it.

Comment: Concerning thread safety: only the following is allowed (1) one thread access (read and/or write) the data or (2) multiple threads only read the data. Saying "only one thread is modifying" isn't enough to ensure thread safety.